# Among Zend, CodeIgniter, and CakePHP, which has the largest development community and is easiest to find work as a freelancer?

Tags: php, frameworks

I'm going to start making my transition from regular, procedural PHP coding to OOP/framework PHP and was wondering which one is best for the two stated factors in my question (1. size of development community  2. steepness of learning curve for getting started with practical use.)

Comment: Duplicate of [best php framework](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=best+php+framework). Sorry, there is no *best*, only *best for you*. How easy it is to find freelance work depends widely and is unanswerable. For development statistics, try http://www.ohloh.net, but that doesn't really mean a lot. All three are active enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at trends.google.com for popularity comparison based on search volume. Try to pick framework which is most suitable. Be sure to look into commercial frameworks too, if they are good. As a freelancer your priority is to get results done fast, so picking Zend might not be good idea.

Look at various related posts here, google for "php framework comparison", look at UI frameworks. Also note that some answers might be made 2 years ago and popularity might have shifted slightly since then.